Spring MVC with Tomcat renders only index.jsp
The problem is that when i run my app with Tomcat it shows only index.jsp in browser. But controllers don't work.
Here's my web.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

  <display-name>spring-course-mvc</display-name>

  <absolute-ordering />

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>

applicationContext.xml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.spring.mvc" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>

My controller:
package com.myapp.spring.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showFirstView() {
        return "first-view";
    }
}

I have view directory in webapp/WEB-INF/ where my first-view.jsp lies. So it looks webapp/WEB-INF/view/first-view.jsp
And when i run project on http://localhost:8080/spring_course_mvc/ I get 404 Error.
Interesting that when i added webapp/index.jsp file I see its content on http://localhost:8080/spring_course_mvc/.
Then i added webapp/first-view.jsp file and on adress http://localhost:8080/spring_course_mvc/first-view.jsp it's working.
Without webapp/index.jsp adress http://localhost:8080/spring_course_mvc/ gives me 404 Error.
pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.myapp.spring.mvc</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring_course_mvc</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>spring_course_mvc Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.7</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>spring_course_mvc</finalName>
  </build>
</project>


First, you need to make sure that if you are using Spring 5, you need to use Tomcat 9.
And if you are using Spring 6, you need to use Tomcat 10.
The next thing that you need to make sure is that your web.xml and your applicationContext.xml are located in webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml and webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml.
Another thing that you need to keep in mind if your application does not run a browser automatically you need to make sure that you are using a correct context root value. In eclipse you can check that by right clicking on your project > Properties > Web Project Settings.


Yes, I'm using Spring 6.1.7 and Tomcat 9.0.88. web.xml and applicationContext.xml are located in WEB-INF. I'm using Intellij idea - so when I click "Run" browser runs automatically.
Added pom.xml

With Spring 6 you need to use Tomcat 10, not Tomcat 9.

Sorry, tried Tomcat 10 and now it works perfectly. Thank you very much!
